# I am getting Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: an object error

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

```html
<div class="table d-inline" *ngFor="let table of tables">
  <span class="ml-2 mt-2 tableBtn" (click)="bookTable(table.tableId)" *ngIf="table.isBooked==false"> 
    {{table.Table}}
  </span>
  <span class="ml-2 mt-2 tableBtn" (click)="bookTable(table.tableId)" *ngIf="table.isBooked == true"> 
    {{table.Table}}
  </span>
</div>
```

**In component.ts**

```
export class RestaurantComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private restaurantService:RestaurantService,
    private actRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  bookTable(id){
    var route= this.actRoute.snapshot.params.id;
    console.log(id)
    let value = {};
    value['isBooked'] = true;
    this.restaurantService.bookTable(route,id,value).catch(error =>{
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
}
```

I am calling this method of service: **In service.ts**

```
bookTable(actid,id,value){
  return this.firestore
    .collection('Restaurants')
    .doc(actid)
    .collection('Tables')
    .doc(id)
    .update(value);
}
```

what I want is to update the field inside ('Tables') doc But I am getting the error when I click the span

> Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: an object

Why am I having this error?

Comment: What exactly are you passing to doc()?  Sounds like it's an object instead of a non-empty string.

Comment: error says it needs non empty string as first argument 
what should i do to remove this error?

Comment: As Doug said, can you mention what you are passing to doc()? You seem to be passing an object

Comment: Yeah i am passing value object

Comment: That's the issue then, you should be passing a string, not an object